# Switched outlet after non-switched

Tags: electrical, receptacle

[image][image]I added an outlet after the one for my garage door. The problem is that somehow the garage door (first in the chain) is not switched but the outlet after it is.

[image: Garage Door Wiring.]

This is how the garage door outlet is wired. I didn't realize it was using the red wire. The new outlet is wired with black wire on one side (the back of the outlet was labeled) and white wire to the other side with the ground connected to green.

I should add that a switch exists before this. I’m confused why this one is always hot but the new outlets are on a switch before all this.

Comment: Can you describe how exactly you connected the new outlet to the existing one and what 'switches' the new outlet?

Comment: You could also [edit] in pictures of the wiring in the boxes, please.

Comment: The wiring of that switch can't be right.  There must be at least 1 wire on the *right side* or else nothing would work.

Comment: Sorry, I think the bottom screw on the left side of the diagram should be black. I just grabbed a stock image.

Answer (score 1):

I looked these wierd things up.

You have no wires connected to the always-hot inputs.

```
Switched hot         Hot in 1 (Switch)
                     ]        Tab (intact, unbroken connects 1&2)
Neutral              Hot in 2 (outlet)
```

You are backfeeding from the switched hot terminal (red) to the hot input terminals (via the switch) which are tied to each other, and that is what's feeding the hot side of the outlet.

Or, the model I found is different than the one you have? But this just appears to be wired wildly wrong. What brand/model number is yours?

Further reading indicates that the instructions for at least one version are minimal and abysmal (reviewer stated it came with none, the website ones were unintelligible even to an electrician, and they had to use a multimeter to sort it out) - evidently the switched hot is internally connected, but does not say that in the instructions, which explains why your's is always on, if red is always-hot in your setup.

Try moving ONLY red to the other side, and see if the (local) switch now switches the (local) outlet.

Anyway, the wiring of the upstream switch you have not shown obviously matters here as well. What is your desired operation of the various switches and outlets?

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll take a look. My goal was just to add an outlet after this but didn't realize this part of the circuit was on a switch before this. To be honest I have no need for this switch. I may just swap this switch out altogether.

Comment: And the local switch (which is the one pictured) does control the outlet just below it.

Comment: Presumably after you moved the red? So, at this point if you cap the black wire that comes in from "upstream" and connect your "downstream" outlets' black to the other screw on the same side as the red now is, they should be unswitched. Your wire colors are "nonstandard" (red would normally be switched, black un-switched, but it's convention, not a rule)- your upstream seems to invert that convention.

Comment: It was working before I moved the red. I haven't had a chance to try moving it yet.

Comment: **...sigh...** Yet your question says it's "always hot." There probably **isn't** an internal connection if it is switching locally as presently wired.

Comment: My mistake. I meant that this whole switch/outlet gets power regardless of the switch on the wall (upstream). But the new outlet I added after this operates on the wall switch for some reason.

Comment: Is it as simple as the Red is the always hot and the black is actually the switched line?

Comment: That appears to be the case.

Comment: Yep, that was indeed the problem. Thank you